# What do we know about Bar Kochba?

Tags: history, messiah, rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef, bar-kochba

Among the failed potential Messiah's was Bar Kochba who was backed by Rabbi Akiva.

What do we know about him? Was he a disciple of Beit Hillel or Beit Shamai or someone else for example?

Comment: Are you also looking for academic sources, or just traditional?

Comment: preferably from chazal

Comment: Related question [Is there any evidence that Rabbi Akiva's students fought with Bar Kochba?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26881/is-there-any-evidence-that-rabbi-akivas-students-fought-alongside-bar-kochba)

Comment: Regarding identifying individuals as from Beis Hillel or Beis Shamai, see [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36635).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most extensive discussion of Bar Kochba in Chazal is in [Eicha Rabbasi 2:4](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/toshba/eyha/2a-2.htm).

He is also mentioned in [Sanhedrin 93b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=93b&format=pdf)

Your specific question - was he a disciple of Beit Hillel or Beit Shamai - is not dealt with in those sources, though I believe that those academies no longer existed at the time of the rebellion.