# Were Shmouel and Rav members of the Beth Hillel or the Beth Shammai?

Tags: historical-figures, amoroim, beis-shammai, beis-hillel

Do we know which Academy Rav and Shmuel belonged to? Maybe they weren't members of any House.

Comment: http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C_(%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90) and http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%91_(%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90) might be good places to start looking.

Comment: The above Wikipedia pages, in English: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_of_Nehardea, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abba_Arika

Comment: I don't think Beis Shammai existed by the time of Rav and Shmuel. By then, the halacha was firmly established in favor of Beis Hillel (*Eruvin* 13b, *Y'rushalmi B'rachos* 1:4; for a list of exceptions, see *Tosafos* on *Sukka* 3a, s.v. דאמר לך).

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36635

Comment: Fred When Beth Shammai started then? And what were these exceptions? Were they authored by Beis Shammai?

Comment: @far22 [Beis Shammai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Shammai) started at the time of [Shammai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shammai) (around 200 years before the time of Rav and Shmuel). There are six exceptions. IIRC, one is about sukka, three are about tzitzis, and two are about meals. They are exceptions because the rabbis ultimately ruled in their favor on those points.

Comment: Thank you. When Beis Shammai stopped to exist then?