# Are Hillel and R. Akiva saying the same thing?

Tags: bein-adam-lachavero, rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef, love, hillel, ahavat-yisrael

[Shabbat 31a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.31a.6?lang=bi):

> אמר לו דעלך סני לחברך לא תעביד זו היא כל התורה כולה ואידך פירושה הוא זיל גמור
>
> [Hillel] said to him: "That which is hateful to you do not do to another; that is the entire Torah, and the rest is its interpretation. Go study."

[Yerushalmi Nedarim 30b](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Nedarim.30b.1?vhe=Mechon_Mamre_Talmud_Yerushalmi&lang=he):

> ואהבת לרעך כמוך. רבי עקיבה אומר זהו כלל גדול בתורה.‏
>
> "Love your neighbor as yourself". R. Akiva said: "This is a great principle of the Torah."

These two statements sound very similar to each other. However, there are some subtle differences:

- Hillel uses a negative formulation, where R. Akiva uses the positive, biblical expression.
- Hillel calls his principle "the entire Torah", whereas R. Akiva's is a "great principle of the Torah".

Are Hillel and R. Akiva in fact expressing identical sentiments?

If yes, why is the wording different? In particular, why would Hillel choose to paraphrase a biblical verse?

If they are actually different ideas, what is the difference?

Comment: They emphasize different, but related subjects. For details, see chapter 32 in the Tanya of the Alter Rebbe, section Likkutei Amarim.

Comment: [R’ Akiva may have been a member of Beis Hillel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/51050/), so it’s not surprising that he’d champion Hillel’s philosophy.

Comment: How do you expect to answer this question? Both are not LeHalachah, just general statements, interestingly R"A's didn't make its way to Bavli(?).

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103332/why-r-akivas-love-your-neighbor-didnt-make-it-to-bavli

Comment: There is a great maamar of Peri Haters who compares this difference to the difference between anochi and look ihie lecha

Comment: This is not the same thing. Hillel gives the first step, to left a space for someone else. To leave him to live as you would want that people will not disturb your life. The second step is after you admitted the right to be free to your friend, to make him good