# Why R' Akiva's "Love your neighbor" didn't make it to Bavli?

Tags: talmud-bavli, rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef, love-thy-neighbor

R'Akiva's famous statement appears in [Safra](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sifra%2C_Kedoshim%2C_Chapter_4.12?lang=he), [Bereyshis Rabbah](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bereishit_Rabbah.24.7?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=he), and ([Yerushalmi Nedarim 30b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jerusalem_Talmud_Nedarim.30b.1)):

> "ואהבת לרעך כמוך" רבי עקיבה אומר זהו כלל גדול בתורה.
>
> "Love your neighbor as yourself". R. Akiva said: "This is a great principle of the Torah."

But it seems that it didn't make it to Bavli. Isn't it? If yes, did anybody mentions a reason for omitting such a great principle?

(This is a follow up to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103320/are-hillel-and-r-akiva-saying-the-same-thing))

Comment: It's interesting to note that Hillel's "reverse" statement (That which is hateful to you, don't do to others) DID make it. Somewhat makes you wonder if some "politics" influenced what was included.

Comment: @DanF Hm, interesting, I dont see " דעלך סני לחברך לא תעביד" appearing before Bavli at all ?! Was it switched?

Comment: @AlBerko Where would you like Hillel’s statement to appear? For whatever reason it didn’t make the cut to be a Mishnah, so it got stuck as a Braisa.

Comment: @AlBerko -- Where does it say that the Yerushalmi is not allowed to contain any nuggets that don't appear in the Bavli?

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi Yerushalmi couldn't copy Bavli as it didn't exist yet. Theoretically, the authors of the Bavli should have had the Yerushalmi handy and if they omitted something I seek a reason for that. See my other questions on "omitting" ruling of previous Rabbis, like https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15579+omitted